# cakephp: how to add language folder to url?

Tags: url, cakephp, seo

I am having a project in 5 languages and I am switching languages by p28n Controller which works perfect! But now, the SEO guys want to have the urls like:

```
www.projekt.com/en for english
www.projekt.com/es for spanish
www.projekt.com/fr for french
```

I am a little bit lost now and don't know who to achieve this?
I this a question for the htaccess file? 
Or do I have to deal with it in Cake?

Please help me out where to start!

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://github.com/CakeDC/i18n) plugin should help you get the urls like you need.

Comment: I installed the plugin and it's displaying the language flags with the added language folder. That's great until this point. But when I am clicking the flags, the language is not changing, I am also not getting an error... Did you use the plugin already successfully? Could you maybe help me with it?